# What is this white powder on a pcb

Tags: pcb, repair

I recently bought a really cheap aux-in FM-transmitter. I didn't expect much from it, but surprisingly, it worked flawlessly the first time I tried it. After a week or so, it started stuttering (turning on and off at a very fast rate, sometimes not turning on at all), and then it failed completely.

I decided to open it up to have a look inside. I found that the battery leads and the whole area around it was covered in some sort of white powder. I have no idea what this is. Could anybody tell me what it is and whether it could have something to do with the failing of the device. It's also under the plastic cover to the side of the battery leads (which you can't see in the picture).

Just to be clear: the device did not get wet.

[image: White powder on pcb]

Comment: The factory this was made in is really a front for a cocaine lab.

Comment: This is "contamination", possibly coming from the battery. Not much can be added without IR spectrometry I guess.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely the contamination is a combination of sticky solder flux and outgassing of battery into white particulate solids around 2-Wire Serial EEPROM and other circuits.

Clean with liberal amounts of isopropyl alcohol, toothbrush, rinse and forced air dry for many hours.

Then beware of battery overcharging.

just to be clear ... flux residue + battery vapour salt condensate + humidity = conductive leakage resistance and capacitance with loss tangent.

**Silicone spray** is a good choice for protection but only if the added pF of dielectric does not add excess latency to high slew rate logic or excess pF to RF tuned circuits.  Silicone RTV is another option or Mylar/Kapton on battery vent interface,  as a deflector or isolation layer not an airtight battery seal.

Comment: almost identical?? you meant exactly olin, morning..

Answer (score 3):

Old batteries tend to leak their electrolyte.  This has a ["crawling salt" effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHhRQKxWXEo), where the white area expands as a wet thin crystal layer.

If the white stuff is dried battery electrolyte, it might be sodium hydroxide (lye) from an alkaline battery.   If so, it's corrosive to skin.  But it can be cleaned up with a wet toothbrush.  Thoroughly dry afterwards, and replace the battery.  Look for any destroyed PCB traces under the white stuff.  Scrape at the green soldermask, since sometimes the copper traces turn out to be empty bubbles with the copper corroded away.